# javascript ondblclick event does not work in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an Android app that shows a webpage in WebView

The webpage has an image with an ondblclick even, this even works fine in normal desktop browser, but it does not work from within my application WebView.

here is the html:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.test.com/test.png" ondblclick="toggleZoomImgInDiv()">
```

The normal onclick event does work, but ondblclick event does not work

May be there is something in Android I have to do to allow ondblclick to work, because I think that may be Android is blocking the ondblclick event so that its own onDoubleTab event works...???

does anyone know..?

Comment: did you try with @@JavascriptInterface method in android

Comment: @Madhu yes I am using this, but the fact is that the function toggleZoomImgInDiv() does not have anything to do in Android, it runs in javascript purely, and it is not being called at all!